# How can I make Tab-key navigation work with popups?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I'm struggling with making a navigation keyboard-accessible, so that the user can <kbd>Tab</kbd> through the links. The problem is with popups that will be shown next to a menu item once it is focused or hovered. Here's a minimal working example:

```css
a.help {
    /* don't show help until explicitly triggered */
    display: none;
}
li:hover + a.help, a:focus + a.help {
    /* show help button when user is about to interact with the original button */
    display: inline;
}
a.help:focus, a.help:hover, a.help:active {
    /* don't hide help button while user interacts with it */
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h3>Actions</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

In Firefox 45, when Focus is on "Edit" and its "(Help)" is visible, the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not focus anything, but the "(Help)" vanishes. The next <kbd>Tab</kbd> will then move to "Delete".

In Chrome 49, it's even worse. When focus is on "Edit", the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not focus anything, and in fact restart the navigation at the page's first link upon the next <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there any way that I can make this work while retaining the general style and document structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw how they do stuff like this in the YAML CSS framework. They don't mess with `display` (or `visibility`, for that matter) and just move the element out of the viewport:

```css
a.help {
    /* don't show help until explicitly triggered */
    position: relative;
    left: -32768px;
}
li:hover + a.help, a:focus + a.help {
    /* show help button when user is about to interact with the original button */
    left: 0;
}
a.help:focus, a.help:hover, a.help:active {
    /* don't hide help button while user interacts with it */
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Actions</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative `tabindex` attribute in order to move element out of <kbd>Tab</kbd> scope:

```html
<h3>Actions</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Edit</a> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">Delete</a> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

> tabindex=-1
>
> When tabindex is set to a negative integer like -1, it becomes
>   programmatically focusable but it isn’t included in the tab order. In
>   other words, it can’t be reached by someone using the tab key to
>   navigate through content, but it can be focused on with scripting.

[Read more about tabindex](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/)

Answer (score -1):

Use "tabindex" attribute:

```css
a.help {
    /* don't show help until explicitly triggered */
    display: none;
}
li:hover + a.help, a:focus + a.help {
    /* show help button when user is about to interact with the original button */
    display: inline;
}
a.help:focus, a.help:hover, a.help:active {
    /* don't hide help button while user interacts with it */
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h3>Actions</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Edit</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">Delete</a> <a class="help" href="#">(Help)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: All that does is make the "Help" links completely inaccessible from tab navigation.